ProcessExtnesions.StartProcessAsCussrentUser throws exception, unable to get user toekn for GetSessionTokenUser, when used in window Service
I am trying to use the ProcessExtensions.StartProcessAsCussrentUser in window application (.net framework 4.8 and windows 10). I want to start a pinned web application in task bar if someone closed it and using the following code
var app_key = "nfhlhahcgkadabofgdcfegfbdcbdghgg";
        var path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge_proxy.exe";
        var arg1s = $"--profile-directory=Default --app-id={app_key} --app-url=https://myapp/auth/realms/abc_Org/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client";
        var str = $"\"{path}\" {arg1s}";
  
        ProcessExtensions.StartProcessAsCurrentUser(str);

I am getting unable to get GetSessionTokenUser. IT works fine with calling "calc.exe" (as per . Please advise.
I am using https://github.com/murrayju/CreateProcessAsUser/tree/master
I want this pinned application should start when I execute this script in Window Service's OnStart for .net framework 4.8 (C#).
